# Association :subject_item not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While trying to create new student Im getting error: Association `:subject_item` not found

File with error is `app/views/students/_form.haml`:

```
= simple_form_for student do |f|
  = f.input :first_name
  = f.input :last_name
  = f.association :subject_items, label_method: :title, value_method: :id, label: 'Subject Items', as: :check_boxes
  = link_to t('shared.back'), students_path, class: 'btn btn-default'
  = f.button :submit
```

Model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subject_item_notes, dependent: :destroy
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :students do
    get :subjects 
  end
  resources :teachers do
    get :subjects 
  end
  resources :reports do
    get :subjects 
  end
  resources :visitors
  resources :subject_items
  root to:  'students#index' 
end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The first thing is that your `f.association` references an association that doesn't exist on your model (`:subject_items` where your association is `:subject_item_notes`). It might be an odd error message from that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is you're calling `f.association :subject_items` when the association doesn't exist.

It *should* look similar to this:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :subject_items
end
```

The other issue I see is that you're adding `check_boxes` to select the various `has_many` associated records...

Your implementation will not work -- `f.association` is only going to work for [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) or [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) (IE `many-to-many`).

Your current setup requires *associated* records to be created in order to "select" them for your `student`; what you *need* is to be able to associate them together as you need.

---

I would do the following:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
end

#app/models/subject.rb
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end

#join table = students_subjects subject_id | student_id
```

This will allow you to use the `f.association` input as follows:

```
 = simple_form_for student do |f|
  = f.input :first_name
  = f.input :last_name
  = f.association :subjects, label_method: :title, value_method: :id, label: 'Subject Items', as: :check_boxes
  = link_to t('shared.back'), students_path, class: 'btn btn-default'
  = f.button :submit
```

---

## Notes

As a secondary note, you have some other things to update in your schematics.

**1. Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
root to:  'students#index'

resources :visitors, :subject_items
resources :students, :teachers, :reports do
  resources :subjects, only: :index
end
```

You can massively improve the efficiency of your route definitions using the [multiple resource definitions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time) in Rails routes.

I've just tested and you *can* added *nested* resources to these routes as well.

--

**2. Models**

In my recommendation above, I used the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

This takes precedence over `has_many :through`, although they achieve similar results, if you **don't** have any associative data in your join model.

You *may* have such data - "subject_items" - in which case it would be recommended that you use a `has_many :through` relationship.

I can update the answer if you need this; Rails documentation explains very well [why you'd favour one over the other](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

In short, I'd say that you should keep your `notes` in a join model ("participations"):

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations #-> equivalent to "classes"
   has_many :subjects, through: :participations
end

#app/models/participation.rb
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | subject_id | student_id | notes | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :student
   belongs_to :subject
end

#app/models/subject.rb
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations
   has_many :students, through: :participations
end
```